# Personal finance software with automatic categorisation

Tags: windows, finance

I am looking for personal finance software. I need to import bank statements (either by [HBCI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FinTS) or .CSV), and then have the software categorise the transactions and produce reports (spending by time period, broken down by category etc). I would obviously have to set up filters for the software to properly categorise the transactions, although some kind of machine learning would be a bonus. I need it to keep track of approximately half a dozen bank accounts.

I have previously used [iOutBank](http://www.outbank.de/) for iOS, which worked fairly well, but doesn't have a Windows version (and its reporting was a bit too limited). However, I would be happy with something similar to iOutBank for Windows.

I am not specifically looking for budgeting or planning features.

I am looking for Windows software, it doesn't have to be free.

Comment: As not all banking software is built to work with banks in countries of the world (and you want yours to work with banks), is there any area to name it *must* support?

Comment: Do you also need to split records - e.g. you have one line which covers three invoices ?

Comment: @Izzy: Support for German banks would be a big plus. However, I would be willing to forego an import by HBCI (and import my statements through CSV files) if the categorisation and reporting functions work well.

Comment: @SQLPolice: No, I don't see that being necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using **[moneyplex](http://www.matrica.de/produkte/produktmpx1.html)** for about 20 years now (since it became available for OS/2). *moneyplex* is a cross-platform<sup>1</sup> finance solution with active support (fast reactions).

- supports HBCI via card, PIN/TAN, mobileTAN, and more
- for banks not offering HBCI, also supports "web banking" access (using page scraping)
- also supports Paypal (for those who need that)
- import/export in various formats
- auto categorization and more
- statistics including graphs
- filters, search
- multi-account and multi-mandant (the latter depending on the version)
- [cost varies](http://www.matrica.de/order/ordermoneyplex.html) depending on version, starting with ~EUR 50 (standard edition) via ~EUR 60 (pro) to ~EUR 140 (business); to see which might fit your needs best, see the [moneyplex feature matrix](http://www.matrica.de/produkte/mpfeatures.html#featurelist) (note: features available also depend on whether the bank offers it – not all banks support all features).

[image: moneyplex statistics] [image: moneyplex statistics]
<sup>*moneyplex* statistics (source: [Matrica](http://www.matrica.de/produkte/produktmpx1.html); click images for larger variants)</sup>

*moneyplex* [supports most (if not all) German banks:](http://www.matrica.de/produkte/mpbanken.html) I e.g. use(d) it successfully with Postbank, Consors, DKB, Sparkasse, Deutsche Bank, MLP Bank, UniCredit, and others (disclosure: I'm beta-tester for *moneyplex*)

---

<sup>**1:** Linux, Mac, OS/2, Windows</sup>